# c++ return trick

Tags: c++, return-value

In c/c++ if a function is boolean you can do a trick like this

```
function1() || function2();
```

so if function1() fails function2() is run. I remember there is also a trick to do something like

```
function() || return false;
```

But "return false" does not give a result back. This kind of stuff is common in other languages like perl.

**Question**

```
function() || (x);
```

what the I put in x so that I get the equivalent of

```
if(function()==false)
    return false;
```

**Edit**

I'm not going to select an answer and let the vote bubble people up. Anyway here's the solution:

first put this somewhere

```
#define treturn(x) ({return (x); 1;})
```

And now you can do this

```
function() || treturn(false)
```

or return what ever you please. Where the treturn part happens only if function()==false. And you can use "&&" aswell

```
function() && treturn(false)
```

treturn in this case will happen when function()==true.

**Note** As many people have already mentioned. You shouldn't do this. And ds27680 posted a good alternative

Comment: I beg to differ.  It very definitely does **not** make the code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to figure out where the "trick" is.  In C++, operators `||`
and `&&` are defined to be short-circuiting, and it is standard practice
to use them as such, e.g. for things like:

```
return p == NULL || *p == '\0';
```

Of course:

```
return function() || return false;
```

is illegal—it is possible in Perl, where it is one of the things 
that make Perl a write only language.

```
return function() || false;
```

is legal, syntactically, but meaningless; it is the exact equivalent of:

```
return function();
```

And your last example should be written:

```
if ( !function() ) {
    return false;
}
```

.  Or more likely with something along the lines of:

```
bool retval = true;
if ( function() ) {
    //  ...
    retval = ...
}
return retval;
```

Why obfuscate when you can make it clear?

Comment: Maybe '(func1() ? Return false : (void)0);'

Comment: heres the trick I finally found it: "function() || {return false; int unused=7;};" And that part can be "#define sret(x) ..." so it can return anything

Comment: "#define treturn(x) ({return (x); int unused; unused=7;})" Now you can do "function() || treturn(false);

Comment: @over_optimistic this also won't work without compiler extension. The operands of `||` must be an `expression`, while compound-statement is not an expression.

Comment: @MooingDuck No.  Return is a type of statement, and not an operator; it can't appear in an expression.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you're really looking for, but I think it's better to do this:

```
return function();
```

...or, if you're feeling verbose:

```
if( function() )
  return true;
else 
  return false;
```

Playing little tricks with the language syntax will only get you in trouble, or punched by a future maintenance programmer down the line.

EDIT:  Per your comments here, if you want to return `false` if the function evaluates to `false` or else continue execution if it evaluates to true, then there can be no simpler, more performant or easer-to-maintain way to do this than:

```
if( !function() )
  return false;

/*
 * MAGIC HAPPENS!
 */
```

EDIT2:  If you are trying to avoid multiple return points, then simply:

```
if( function() )
{ 
  /*
   * MAGIC HAPPENS!
   */
}
```

Comment: The verbose version is IMHO not the way to go. Just name your function properly.

Comment: If function() == true I don't want to return anything and continue with execution of my code.

Comment: @over_optimistic No you don't.  At least not if you want others to be able to understand what you've written.  `return` statements in the middle of functions are very confusing, and make analyzing the code unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: you forgot `return function() ? true : false;` for when your indecisive :P

Comment: I personally prefer the multiple return points. If you have a lot of return-value checking, you may end up writing your important code nested by 10 indents.

Comment: Multiple return points versus single return points is a matter of style and company policy more often than anything else, but it can also impact how you write code.

Comment: @Shahbaz that is exactly what I'm doing. "read_input() || return false". @ John first edit is how I currently structure my code. In James post I left a comment of how to do the trick.

Comment: @over_optimistic:  I saw what you posted, but the big question remains:  **why do you want to do this?**

Comment: anyone else see irony in putting "more readable" and "perl" in the same justification?

Answer (score 1):

In case of just `false`
`return function()`

Else

`return function() || function2()`

But beware, I'm not sure if the order of the OR statement is defined.

If it is, and function() returns true, function2() is not evaluated.

Comment: or statements in C++ are evaluated left to right (with short-circuiting)

Comment: order of logical operators is defined in standard

Comment: yes, it is defined by the language. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/

Comment: @Ed Heal, evaluation order of binary+ operands and function  arguments is not guarantied

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get the equivalent of:

```
if(function()==false)
    return false;
```

would be:

```
return function();
```

:-)

Now getting serious... and to address the comments, if you have code after the if then in my humble opinion you already wrote the form most C++ developers would have no readability problems with (for completeness sake):

```
if(function()==false)
    return false;
```

or:

```
   if ( !function() )
      return false;
```

Anything else is either not possible or of dubious value in my opinion...

Comment: Not necessarily; maybe if it's `true` you don't want to return yet.

Comment: Your solution is simple and correct. Why do some programmers want to make things complicated and unreadable?